# ScrollView not allowing me to scroll

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

I've been working on my first kivy application to get to the know and understand the language. I'm currently stuck on getting my ScrollView to actually scroll. I've looked up many different answers and videos on the subject. Below is my current script for the ScrollView. Can anyone assist me with this?

```
class SearchMovie(GridLayout):
    global MovieList
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        
        
        
        
        scrolly = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height*.9))
        subgrid = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=20)
        movlist = MovieList[0]["Box1"]
        nmovlist = []
        for i in movlist:
            nmovlist.append(i)
        nmovlist.sort()
        for i in nmovlist:
            movlab = Label(text=i)
            subgrid.add_widget(movlab)
        scrolly.add_widget(subgrid)
        self.add_widget(scrolly)
        
        
        self.goback = Button(text="Go Back", background_color =[0, 0, 1, 1], pos_hint={'bottom':1, 'center_x':1})
        self.goback.bind(on_press=self.go_back)
        self.add_widget(self.goback)
        
    def go_back(self, instance):
        MovieScript.screen_manager.current = "Main Page"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `height` of the `subgrid`. The default is `size_hint=(1,1)`, which make the `subgrid` the same size as the `ScrollView`, so there is nothing to scroll. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
class SearchMovie(GridLayout):
    global MovieList
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        scrolly = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height*.9))
        subgrid = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=20, size_hint_y=None)  # use size_hint_y here
        movlist = MovieList[0]["Box1"]
        nmovlist = []
        for i in movlist:
            nmovlist.append(i)
        nmovlist.sort()
        label_height = 40  # this will be the height of each Label
        total_height = 0  # this will be the total height of the subgrid
        for i in nmovlist:
            movlab = Label(text=i, size_hint_y=None, height=label_height)  # set height
            total_height += label_height + 20  # sum heights (plus spacing)
            subgrid.add_widget(movlab)
        subgrid.height = total_height  # set actual height of subgrid
        scrolly.add_widget(subgrid)
        self.add_widget(scrolly)
        
        
        self.goback = Button(text="Go Back", background_color =[0, 0, 1, 1], pos_hint={'bottom':1, 'center_x':1})
        self.goback.bind(on_press=self.go_back)
        self.add_widget(self.goback)
        
    def go_back(self, instance):
        MovieScript.screen_manager.current = "Main Page"
```

Another way to do this is to use the kivy language. For example, you can make a rule for the `SearchMovie` class:

```
kv = '''
<SearchMovie>:
    cols: 1
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        text: "Go Back"
        background_color: [0, 0, 1, 1]
        pos_hint: {'bottom': 1, 'center_x': 1}
        on_press: root.go_back()
'''
```

Then your actual `SearchMovie` class can be:

```
class SearchMovie(GridLayout):
    global MovieList

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        subgrid = self.ids.grid
        movlist = MovieList[0]["Box1"]
        nmovlist = []
        for i in movlist:
            nmovlist.append(str(i))
        nmovlist.sort()
        for i in nmovlist:
            movlab = Label(text=i, size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            subgrid.add_widget(movlab)

    def go_back(self, instance):
        MovieScript.screen_manager.current = "Main Page"
```

Just be sure to load the above `kv` string before you create the `SearchMovie` instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, John!!! It appears to be letting me scroll now! However, and I hate to bother you again, it only lets me scroll a little bit and it keeps going back to the top of the list.  How can I prevent that from happening? My MovieList[0]["Box1"] has like 120 labels in there so it definitely should have space to properly scroll